# How to use electron-positioner

Tags: javascript, windows, electron, transparency, positioning

There is no explicit example of how to position your ELECTRON JS app to a specific area. The only syntax is available on GitHub, and it does not describe it well.

Comment: Can you please share what you have tried yet?

Answer (score 1):

It's quite straight forward.  Consider this code that positions the mainWindow once the *ready* event fires. You should be able to drop in the 'ready' event below to demonstrate the positioner.

```
// load the module
const Positioner = require('electron-positioner');

let mainWindow = null;

// create the main window
async function createWindow () {      
  mainWindow = new BrowserWindow({
    height: 420,
    width: 600,
    x: 0, // default position left
    y: 0, // default position top
    show: false,
    webPreferences: {
      nodeIntegration: true,
      preload: path.join(__dirname, 'node_modules', 'electron', 'dist', 'electron-bridge.js')
    }
});     

// reposition after creating the window.
app.on('ready', async () => {
  await createWindow();
  let positioner = new Positioner(mainWindow);
  positioner.move('bottomRight');
});
```

Of course this affect may be achieved with the x and y values via the BrowserWindow constructor, but it is quite handy to have canned positions provided by the module.